# Centos - PhpMyAdmin showing blank screen

Tags: centos, php, phpmyadmin

I have just installed PhpMyAdmin, and when i try to access it it just shows a blank screen. I suspected this is because i followed a tutorial on how to secure php and disabled multiple settings, so i reinstalled php to reset the php.ini file, but that didn't fix the problem... Now i think it maybe because of the suhosin php security mod, or i am missing a php module.
My php info is accessible here: http://87.92.41.2/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have all the php extensions installed, if it's showing 200 in the console when you access the page but the page is blank, chances are you are missing some extensions. Try installing these if you don't have them aready-

```
$sudo dnf install php-pdo
$sudo dnf install php-mysql
$sudo dnf install php-mysqli
```

Note: If you are using yum as installer then you can do the same with yum

There might be more reasons but this is a very prominent one on new servers and also the display errors are disabled by default on new installation, so you might not even see some of the warning messages.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what else is running on that public (I assume based on your link) web server, I recommend looking at the error logs (located in   /var/log/httpd/php_error_log.log according to the phpinfo) on your server and possibly allowing PHP to show errors while you resolve the problem. As you suggest the most likely issue is something cusing a problem like an HTTP 500 or similar where the server has a problem but is configured not to show an error.

Comment: By default on CentOS, phpmaydmin respond only to requests from localhost, so if you are trying to access from another host and you disabled the error reporting maybe you are missing the 403 - Access denied error. Anyway check the error log first.

Comment: I have put my ip adress in the list of allowed ips, so that's not the problem here

Comment: Turns out the error was that /usr/share/phpMyAdmin wasn't in the allowed paths: http://pastebin.com/VEh3SUVX. I tried adding it to allowed directories in httpd.conf with a <Directory> directive. That didn't fix the problem, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Checking link http://87.92.41.2/phpmyadmin now I can see a:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.

By default phpmyadmin is only accessible from localhost on CentOS, if you want to make it accessible from external host you must edit `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`:

```
 # Apache 2.4
 <RequireAny>
   Require ip 127.0.0.1
   Require ip ::1
   Require ip 10.10.10.1/24 # TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM A SPECIFIC IP RANGE
   Require all granted # TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM EVERY IP
 </RequireAny>
```

And then restart apache:

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

Please be careful, allow access from every IP can be a security flaw limit it to a specific, trust, range or, at leas, use a very strong password and set up HTTPS.

Comment: I know, i've done that.

Answer (score 0):

It's so annoying that there is no specific error on the screen. The cause in my case is: **"set writing permission for `config.inc.php`"**. So, we only set *reading* and *executing* permission only:

```
sudo chmod -R 555 /etc/phpMyAdmin
```

**Note:** if we only set reading permission, the configuration won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install extensions like this:

```
dnf install php-mysqli php-pdo php-json php-gettext
```

or

```
yum install php-mysqli php-pdo php-json php-gettext
```

Perhaps you should install another extension.

After it restart apache or php-fpm:

```
systemctl restart httpd
systemctl restart php-fpm
```

or

```
service httpd restart
service php-fpm restart
```